# Ler conteúdo de arquivo ZIP sem gravar no disco

Tags: c#, .net, arquivo-zip, amazon-aws

No programa que estou escrevendo faço o download de um arquivo ZIP pela internet
e preciso então fazer upload dos arquivos extraídos do ZIP para outro lugar.

Acontece que não consigo encontrar um modo de ler o conteúdo desse arquivo ZIP - agora um Stream - sem antes criar um FileStream e gravá-lo no disco. Eu preferiria mil vezes trabalhar tudo em memória. Hoje faço assim (com `System.IO`):

```
string zipLocation = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\teste.zip";

//faz o download e grava no disco
using (GetObjectResponse response = await S3Client.GetObjectAsync(req))
using (Stream responseStream = response.ResponseStream)
using (FileStream fileStream = File.Create(zipLocation))
{
    responseStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
    fileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    using (var zip = new ZipArchive(file, ZipArchiveMode.Read))
    {
        //loop pelos arquivos dentro do ZIP
        foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in zip.Entries)
        {
            //faz o upload
        }
    }
}
```

Como pode-se observar, tive que escrever o arquivo no disco usando File.Create(). Como fazer sem essa parte?

Answer (score 2):

Já viste o [DotNetZip](https://github.com/DinoChiesa/DotNetZip).

```
using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read("omeuzip"))
{
  ZipEntry FicheiroZip = zip["documento.txt"];
  FicheiroZip.Extract(OutputStream);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Olha, peço até desculpas por ter aberto essa pergunta. Trabalhando um pouco mais no meu código consegui utilizar MemoryStream, sim. Antes pensei que não era possível. Tentei excluir a pergunta e não dava mais.

```
...
using (GetObjectResponse response = await S3Client.GetObjectAsync(req))
using (Stream responseStream = response.ResponseStream)
using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream()) //funciona perfeitamente
```